# adb unable to see android device in bootloader mode here's the lsusb verbose information how do I install this?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb

```
Bus 006 Device 007: ID 2207:310d  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2207 
  idProduct          0x310d 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
Bus 006 Device 007: ID 2207:310d  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2207 
  idProduct          0x310d 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
  MaxPower              400mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 
      bInterfaceProtocol      5 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5

 bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength            8
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  ** UNRECOGNIZED:  03 10 00
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: I have this in 51-android.rules SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="2207",ATTRS{idProduct}=="310d", MODE"0600", OWNER="mark"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="2207",ATTRS{idProduct}=="0006", MODE"0600", OWNER="mark"                                                                                                                      and this in adb_usb.ini   0x2207

Comment: also the device is a POS and has no display in bootloader mode.  I wouldn't even know it was on without lsusb.  If the model helps at all, it's an em756.

Comment: Thanks for trolling me and not addressing the question.  This seems like a great community.

Comment: Whats the output of `adb devices` ? showing lsusb is not going to tell us anything.

Comment: Nothing.  I wouldn't be asking the question if it showed up in adb devices.  And yes I've issued adb kill-server and restarted the service, rebooted and unplugged it.

Comment: did you run as root   `sudo adb devices`

Comment: It initially didn't show up at all while plugged in, that's why i edited the .rules and .ini file.  After that it showed up and i was able to issue the reboot into bootloader command. And yes i wish it was that simple.

Comment: By the way, thank you for trying to address my question.  Honestly.

Comment: i had a similar problem, running sudo adb devices was not enough because the privileges were required by adb-server and not adb command. Try to kill the server and start it with sudo, also do it in one command like `sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server`

Comment: I tried concatenating the server restart commands as spinning top suggested, no dice.  As for download mode i can't even go into that mode.  I issued the adb reboot download command and it didn't recognize anything after adb reboot so it just restarted.

Comment: I tried issuing the fastboot devices command in fastboot mode and i just didn't do anything.  Curiously in fastboot mode the device id changes again and differs both from bootloader and simply being connected while on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in download mode. Try using 
`fastboot devices` and see if that recognises your device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the android rules properly in your udev folder? 
In the download mode or fastboot, adb will not recognize your device. It's not meant for that. Fastboot will only be able to do so.

Comment: see my first comment.

Comment: in fastboot mode, the product id is 0006 and of course the vendor id has not changed.

Comment: Did you reboot after setting up the android rules.?

Comment: yes. I rebooted.  I set those up yesterday.